# Change dataframe by group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this

```
activity   time      date
0    Phone  04:00  20210810
1    Phone  08:30  20210810
2   Coffee  10:30  20210810
3    Lunch  04:00  20210810
4    Phone  10:30  20210810
5    Phone  04:00  20210810
6    Lunch  08:30  20210810
7    Lunch  10:30  20210810
0    Phone  08:45  20210811
1  Pooping  08:50  20210811
2   Coffee  10:30  20210811
3    Lunch  04:00  20210811
4    Phone  10:30  20210811
5  Meeting  04:00  20210811
6    Lunch  08:30  20210811
7    Lunch  10:30  20210811
```

and i need to change it to :

```
                 
date     activity   time
20210810 Phone     04:00
                   08:30
                   10:30
                   04:00
         Coffee    10:30
         Lunch     04:00
                   08:30
                   10:30
20210811 Phone     08:45
                   10:30
         Pooping   08:50
         Coffee    10:30
         Meeting   04:00
         Lunch     04:00
                   08:30
                   10:30
```

Basically sort by date, activity and then add '' for the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Set as index and sort:

```
df.set_index(['date', 'activity']).sort_index()
```

Or, if the values need to be sorted as well:

```
    df.set_index(['date', 'activity']).sort_values(by='time').sort_index()
```

By default, in jupyter/ipython the index will display only the first value of the successive rows. If you need another format, please update your question.